# How to Call URL in API Nested Array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, image, api

I'm new to REST API and am having some trouble. I'm trying to call data from an array that's nested within a dictionary. While I've been able to pull data from other variables fine, this is giving me some problems. For reference, the URL I need is labeled "front default," inside the "sprites" array. Furthermore, the URL is that of an image, and I am using Alamofire Image to display images. I will include the code I've used thus far to call other variables, along with a screenshot of the API's structure.

[Screenshot of API hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jac5.png)

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
import SwiftyJSON
import Siesta

class PokeInfo {
var name: String
var id: Int
var abilities: [String]
var types: [String]




// converts dictionary into string
init?(jsonDictionary: [String: Any]) {
    //guard used to check if value entered in search bar matches a name in API data
    guard let name = jsonDictionary["name"] as? String,

        let id = jsonDictionary["id"] as? Int,
        //abilities data nested. First must be set to string
        let abilities = jsonDictionary["abilities"] as? [[String: Any]],
    let types = jsonDictionary["types"] as? [[String: Any]]
    else {
            return nil
    };


    var abilityNames: [String] = []
     var typeNames: [String] = []


    //targets nested data, going inside dictionary to find attributes of that element
    for abilityDictionary in abilities {

        guard let ability = abilityDictionary["ability"] as? [String: Any], let name = ability["name"] as? String else { break }

        abilityNames.append(name)
    };
    for typeDictionary in types {

        guard let type = typeDictionary["type"] as? [String: Any], let name = type["name"] as? String else { break }

        typeNames.append(name)
    }


    self.name = name
    self.id = id
    self.abilities = abilityNames
    self.types = typeNames


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Swift 4 you should be using [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) for JSON which is now part of the language.  Here is a Playground example:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class PokeInfo: Codable {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
    var abilities: [String]
    var types: [String]
}

let pokeString = """
{
"name": "test",
"id": 1,
"abilities": ["a", "b", "c"],
"types": ["x", "y", "z"]
}
"""
let pokeData = pokeString.data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let pokeInfo = try! decoder.decode(PokeInfo.self, from: pokeData)
print(pokeInfo.abilities)
```

the output is:

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```